# How to convert directory objects to strings - Powershell

Tags: string, windows, powershell, type-conversion

I have an array of paths that I retrieved from some registry queries. As of right now, they are still being returned as directory objects, but I need to convert them to just an array of strings. What is the most efficient way to do this in PS?

Code:

```
  $found_paths = @();

  $uninstall_keys = getRegistrySubkeys "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" '\\Office[\d+.*]';
  if ($uninstall_keys -ne $null) 
  {
    foreach ($key in $uninstall_keys)
    {
      $product_name = getRegistryValue $key "DisplayName";
      $version = getRegistryValue $key "DisplayVersion";
      $base_install_path = getRegistryValue $key "InstallLocation"; 
      $full_install_path = Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath $base_install_path | Where-Object Name -match '^Office\d{1,2}\D?' | Select-Object FullName;

      $found_paths += ,$full_install_path
    }
  }

  write-output $found_paths;
```

Output:

```
 FullName                                          
--------                                          
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15
```

Desired output:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\OFFICE15
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15
```

Comment: As an aside: you only ever need `;` to terminate a statement in PowerShell if you place multiple statements _on the same line_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **most efficient** approach is to **use [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** (`(...).PropName`):

```sh
$full_install_path = (
  Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath $base_install_path | Where-Object Name -match '^Office\d{1,2}\D?'
).FullName
```

Note: It sounds like maybe just *one* directory-info object is returned by your command, but the approach would also work with *multiple* ones, in which case an *array* of paths is returned.

The more objects you need to deal with, the greater the speed advantage of member-access enumeration vs. a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-ExpandProperty` solution is (see below).

---

As for **what you tried**:

```sh
... | Select-Object FullName
```

doesn't return the *value* of the input objects' `.FullName` property, it returns a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a `.FullName`  property that contains that value. To get the value only, you need to use `... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

```sh
$found_paths += , $full_install_path
```

You probably meant `$found_paths += $full_install_path` - there is no need to construct an *array* (with `,`) on the RHS first.

In fact, if you do so and `$full_install_path` happened to contain *multiple elements*, you'd get a *nested* array.

Taking a step back: **It is much more efficient to let PowerShell automatically collect outputs from a loop statement in an array for you**:

```sh
  $uninstall_keys = getRegistrySubkeys "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" '\\Office[\d+.*]'
  if ($null -ne $uninstall_keys) 
  {
    # Collect the `foreach` loop's outputs in an array.
    [array] $found_paths = foreach ($key in $uninstall_keys)
    {
      $product_name = getRegistryValue $key "DisplayName"
      $version = getRegistryValue $key "DisplayVersion"
      $base_install_path = getRegistryValue $key "InstallLocation"
      # Get and output the full path.
      (Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath $base_install_path | Where-Object Name -match '^Office\d{1,2}\D?').FullName
    }
  }

  $found_paths # output (implicit equivalent of Write-Output $found_paths
```